# Calculate row number over group in linq and take only those with row number 1?

Tags: c#, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

What would be the LINQ counterpart to get the row number over partition and then get only those records having row number as 1?

Here is the SQL which I want to convert to its LINQ implementation:

```
select
   ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY TASKKEY  ORDER BY CREATEDON DESC) as rn
   ,pwt.*
from
   TaskClass pwt
where pwt.STATUS = 0
```

Here is the LINQ i have tried so far, but it doesnt  give correct result

```
            var output = Result.GroupBy(t => t.TaskKey)
            .SelectMany(g => g.Select((j, i) =>
                new
               {
                   //Rest of the fields 
                   ,
                   rn = i + 1 //Row number
               }

                )
            )
            .Where(e => e.rn == 0)
            .Select(
            y => new TaskClass
            {
                //Rest of the fields
            }

            ).OrderBy(o => o.Id )
            .ToList<TaskClass>()
            );
```

In a nutshell, I want to find which entry from the rows having the same TaskKey has latest CreatedOn, but in pure LINQ.

Comment: So you want to `GroupBy` TaskKey and then `OrderBy` CreatedOn and take the `Last` one?

Comment: @mjwills Yes, Last as in the one which was created latest as per CreatedOn. I want which entry from the rows having the same TaskKey has latest CreatedOn

Comment: @mjwills. so you mean the Last() operator. Let me give it a quick try. You should add it as an answer so that in case it does work I can upvote it and mark as accepted answer.

Comment: @mjwills I am still getting incorrect results. Can you answer with the LINQ implementation you are inferring to ?

Comment: If you provide a [mcve] with sample inputs, and expected results, you are more likely to get people having a go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why do you need the row numbers but, if you want distinct by the TaksKey and get the latest entry:

```
var output = Result.GroupBy(a => a.TaskKey)
    .ToDictionary(a => a.Key, b => b.Value.OrderBy(CreatedOn).First());
```

Same with some filter.

```
var output = Result.Where(a => a.STATUS == 0)
    .GroupBy(a => a.TaskKey)
    .ToDictionary(a => a.Key, b => b.Value.OrderBy(CreatedOn).First());
```

I have not tested this so please check the date order, if it doesn't fit just use `Last` instead of `First`.